# Solrcloud duplicate documents with id field

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am using solrcloud-4.3.0 and zookeeper-3.4.5 on windows machine. I have a collection of index with unique field "id". I observed that there were duplicate documents in the index with same unique id value. As per my understanding this should not happen cause the purpose of the unique field is to avoid such situations. Can anyone help me out here what causes this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In the "/conf/schema.xml" file there is a XML element called "", which seems to be "id" by default... that is supposed to be your "key".

However, according to Solr documentation (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#Use_cases_which_do_not_require_a_unique_key) you do not always need to have always to have a "unique key", if you do not require to incrementally add new documents to an existing index... maybe that is what is happening in your situation. But I also had the impression you always needed a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to add an answer to this question, but it is also possible to duplicate documents with unique keys/fields by merging indexes with duplicate documents/fields.

Apparently when indexes are merged either via the lucene IndexMergeTool or the solr CoreAdminHandler, any duplicate documents will be happily appended to the index. (as of lucene and solr 4.6.0)

de-duplication seems to happen at retrieval time.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes